# How could I add new property into a JSON string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

By JSON *text*, I mean the return value of JSON.stringify. I know how to do this with JSON object, but I couldn't figure out how to do this with JSON *text* (add new attribute/element, say "sn":"1" to JSON *text*, but its structure is kept and I don't need to stringify it again), can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you unpack the JSON, update it, and stringify it again?

Comment: Any string manipulation function would suffice.

Comment: The question may not be best practise, but its a legitimate question that I don't think deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you'd want to do this - why not just add the property *before* you stringify it?

But if you must, given a string that contains JSON:

```
var myJSON = '{"prop1":"val1","prop2":"val2"}';
```

You can easily add a property to the beginning by doing this:

```
myJSON = '{' + '"sn":"1",' + myJSON.substr(1);
```

Or add it to the end:

```
myJSON = myJSON.replace(/}$/, ',"sn":"1"' + '}');
```

Or use whatever other combination of [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) manipulation functions takes your fancy...

If you want to add the new property in a specific place within the string, say inside a nested object or array or something, well, again some kind of regex or combination of `.indexOf()` and `.substr()` or something could do it, but really I think it's nuts to approach it this way.

Obviously the above code can be wrapped up in a function, and `'"sn":"1"'` can be replaced with a parameter or variable name or whatever - but *why*?

Note also that I've assumed above that there will be at least one existing property and inserted a comma accordingly- up to you to make that smarter if you want to allow for empty objects.

P.S. There aren't "JSON strings" and "JSON objects": *all* JSON is a string. In JavaScript one way of creating objects is with the object literal syntax that inspired JSON, but there's no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: Sorry I did not point out the reason that I want to do this. The thing is I need to figure out the length of the JSON text before adding a new attribute/element to it. But...as you point out, i still can stringfy --> get the length --> de-stringfy -- adding a new attribute/element --> stringfy it. Thanks a a lot!

Comment: In that case you don't need to de-stringify: you've still got a reference to the original object so just add the property and stringify again.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to do it the way you're suggesting... just turn it back into an Object, add your field and stringify it again! Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to parse it somehow. The most straightforward way is probably un-stringifying it to object/array/literal data. But if you don't want to do that, you could either use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), or methods of the `String` object like [substr](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#substr) to manipulate the string directly.